# susy framework generating incorrect % widths

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

First time using the susy compass plugin, I've created a fluid 12 col grid and have added two columns to this as shown in snipper below. My problem however is that the % seem to be incorrect, my parent container is 100%, my main col 9,12 cols and the secondary col 3,12. I guess these should result in main col = 75% and sec col = 25% but instead my results are main col = 74.57627% and sec col = 23.72881% ?

**CSS/SCSS:**

```
    $total-columns: 12;
    $column-width: 4em;
    $gutter-width: 1em;
    $grid-padding: 0;

    $show-grid-backgrounds : true;
    $container-style: fluid;

    .l-main-news{
      width: columns(9,12);
      float: left;

      > div{
        width: columns(4.5,9);
        float: left;
      }

}

.l-side-news{
  width: columns(3,12);
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Is it just the values that are generated that bother you or does it actually impact how the elements fit together?

Comment: yeah its impacting how the elements fit together and also I cant understand why its making the wrong calculation. It feels like its accounting for margin or padding

Comment: worked it out, I had to set $gutter-width to 0